# GSP rendering programmatically

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

Suppose I have a gsp snippet stored in my database. How do I programmatically merge it with a data model to produce a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The applicationContext of any Grails app contains a bean named

```
groovyPagesTemplateEngine
```

By default this is a instance of [GroovyPagesTemplateEngine](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/pages/GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.html). So you might use code like this in your controller or service:

```
class MyService/MyController {
    def groovyPagesTemplateEngine

    String renderGSPToString(String uri, Map model) {
        groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(uri).make(model).toString()
    }
}
```

NB: this snippet is not really taken from running code, it should just clarify the idea.

Comment: In fact I want the 'createTemplate' that takes the GSP text itself as input, instead of the uri of a file. But that's the way. Thanks.

Comment: if the template's code is in a String, consider using the SimpleTemplateEngine http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/text/SimpleTemplateEngine.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a DIRTY (but working) way of rendering complex gsps offline using groovyPageRenderer with substituted scriptsource. In that case you have access to all gsp syntax including `g:if` etc..

First define two dummy classes:

```
class StringPageLocator extends GrailsConventionGroovyPageLocator {
    GroovyPageScriptSource findViewByPath(String content) {
        return new StringScriptSource(content)
    }
}

class StringScriptSource implements GroovyPageScriptSource{

    String content

    public StringScriptSource(String content) {
        this.content=content
    }

    @Override String suggestedClassName() { "DummyName" }
    @Override boolean isPublic() { true }
    @Override String getScriptAsString() { return content }
    @Override boolean isModified() { true }
    @Override String getURI() { "DummyURI" }
}
```

And then you can use it as such:

```
def groovyPageLocator // Injected automaticaly to service/controller etc...

groovyPageRenderer.groovyPageLocator=new StringPageLocator()
String output=groovyPageRenderer.render(
    view:'Hello2 ${user} <g:if test="${test}">TRUE!!!</g:if>',
    model:[user:'test user2',test:true]
```

)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a controller method that does what you want. Then you will have an HTTP api to accomplish what you want. The controller method's template will have a `<g:render>` tag, appropriately parameterized.